# Lyman Zerga's taste of steel touching his skin

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, oceans-eleven

In *Ocean's Eleven*, Saul (portraying Lyman Zerga) is going into the casino with Benedict and the twins (as Zerga's bodyguards) when some random guy recognizes him. Zerga tells his bodyguards to take him away and turns to Benedict:

> Mr. Benedict, please, I have never enjoyed the touch of steel to my skin.

Benedict refuses him, and they proceed.

**Why did Zerga do this? What is the significance and point of this?**

My interpretation is that Zerga is trying to make Benedict forget what just happened with some random request. Benedict falls for it, refuses the request (so as to assert who is in charge in their relationship), and they move on. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think your interpretation is correct, i always figured it was an in-character way of trying to show Benedict how "inconsequential" it was that Zerga was accosted, and that the handcuff on his wrist was of more importance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When that random guy identifies and calls Saul, Saul had no option except act as he never met the guy and he needed to make sure that scene has nothing to do with who he is, He needed to keep the act as Zerga and Zerga is a guy who is very rich and lived in a higher society.

> Mr. Benedict, please, I have never enjoyed the touch of steel to my skin.

That line was an attempt to continue his act as Zerga and he needed to show that he was not used to carry his own bags and he shows that he needs to get rid from the carrying of his own bag. Continuing and ensuring he is actually rich proud man.